# MongoDB: How to query arrays in embedded document within several depth?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nested

If this is the one questioned before, please let me know.
But I couldn't get exact answer from official docs or stackoverflow.

My mongodb document looks like this.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("614e1b600146c86a7d5cb524"),
    "hash": "hash_1",
    "logs": [
        {
            "address": "address_1",
            "topics": [
                "AAA",
            ],
        },
        {
            "address": "address_2",
            "topics": [
                "CCC",
                "DDD",
            ],
        },
    ],
},

{
    "_id": ObjectId("614e1b470146c86a7d5cacd0"),
    "hash": "hash_2",
    "logs": [
        {
            "address": "address_3",
            "topics": [
                "EEE",
                "FFF"
            ],
        },
    ],
}
```

I only want to query documents that the first value of `topics` field of an element in `logs` field equals with certain value, say `"CCC"`.
So can be said like this.

```
results = []
logs.map((log) => log.topics[0] = "CCC" ? results.push(log))
return results
```

And I only want elements in logs field with that meet the condition above.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$match` match the condition to reduce document
- `$project` filter array

data

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("614e1b600146c86a7d5cb524"),
    "hash": "hash_1",
    "logs": [
      {
        "address": "address_1",
        "topics": [
          "AAA"
        ]
      },
      {
        "address": "address_2",
        "topics": [
          "CCC",
          "DDD"
        ]
      }
    ]
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("614e1b470146c86a7d5cacd0"),
    "hash": "hash_2",
    "logs": [
      {
        "address": "address_3",
        "topics": [
          "EEE",
          "FFF"
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

aggregate

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "logs.topics.0": "CCC"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      hash: 1,
      logs: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$logs",
          as: "log",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  "$$log.topics",
                  0
                ]
              },
              "CCC"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

result

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("614e1b600146c86a7d5cb524"),
  "hash": "hash_1",
  "logs": [
    {
      "address": "address_2",
      "topics": [
        "CCC",
        "DDD"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HwoiFuZptyI)

Comment: Thanks for your quick and correct answer. Btw, I have one more question. What if I want to apply a condition for second element of `topics` array. It seems like there is no expression like `$eq: [{$second: "$$log.topics"},"DDD"]` And second is not the last one. There are other elements folllowing like `"EEE", "FFF"...`

Comment: I update my answer. Using `$arrayElemAt` can get second or third element.

Comment: You saved me a day! Thanks a lot @YuTing. I finally was able to get exact elements I wanted with `$and` expression and your answer.